# Remove the star icon from any stashed NLA track with a given name

Tags: python, animation, scripting, nla-editor

I was wondering how to remove the star icon (see screenshot) from a stashed track with bpy. I want to loop through all selected objects whose stashed star track's name equals a string.
[image]

For future work, I would also like to know where I can find these variable paths. I am always having a hard time finding those references for the whole Blender animation system, so I was wondering where you people could find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DNR:

You need to find the relevant NLATrack and change the `is_solo` value to `False`.

```py
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.animation_data and obj.animation_data.nla_tracks:
        for track in obj.animation_data.nla_tracks:
            if track.name == 'PUT_TRACK_NAME_HERE':
                track.is_solo = False
```

### The way I figured this out

- Reading  the ["NLA Tracks"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/tracks.html#tracks) manual section to see what the star means.
- Knowing from previous experience, although you could find out by searching the web, that each object that has animation data stores the NLA Tracks in `obj.animation_data.nla_tracks`.
- Reading the Python manual for [`bpy.types.NlaTrack`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NlaTrack.html) to discover that the variable corresponding to the star appears to be `is_solo`.
- Using the Python console to check the assumption by stashing an action plus creating a couple of NLA strips and then interactively trying to change `is_solo` for a strip to see if it worked.  Here's a transcription of such a test:

```
>>> o = C.active_object
>>> n = o.animation_data.nla_tracks
>>> s=n['[Action Stash]']
>>> s.is_solo
False
>>> s.is_solo = True
>>> s.is_solo = False
```

obviously doing the last two while looking at the NLA editor to see if the star on the stashed track changed.

Once I was certain of that, I would convert the interaction into
maintainable code which is what I would normally present in an answer:

```py
obj = bpy.context.active_object
nlatracks = obj.animation_data.nla_tracks
stashed = nlatracks['[Action Stash]']
stashed.is_solo = False
```

You want to iterate through selected objects.  If you look at the manual for [`bpy.types.Context`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html)  you'll see that it has a member for this, so your loop could look like

```py
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.animation_data and obj.animation_data.nla_tracks:
        for track in obj.animation_data.nla_tracks:
            if track.name == 'PUT_TRACK_NAME_HERE':
                track.is_solo = False
```

replacing the track name with the one you want. The if statement is because not all selected objects may have animation data, and not every object with animation data has NLA tracks.

### Tools

There are several ways to find these things out.  I didn't mention one of the two most useful.  If you Edit Preferences, in the Interface tab, under Display there are checkboxes for *Developer Extras* and *Python Tooltips*.  Both are useful, but Python Tooltips allows you to hover over many fields and get a tooltip that will give you a starting point for finding out what data structure goes with that field.

I did mention using the [Python Console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html). You can find a lot out by using it, especially using completion to find out what members an object has and help to find the arguments for a function.

The Python console is featured in the Scripting workspace, along with the Info window.  Often, you can perform a task interactively and find out from the info window what ops were called.

The System Console is not featured, because it is handled differently in different OSes.  On Windows, you can use the topbar menu Window → Toggle System Console.

People often discount the manuals, but they do contain useful information and the Blender Python manual has the best documentation on the data structures, although you have to spend time learning how to navigate the various sections.

Search engines are very useful.  Stack Exchange has a lot of questions on related topics and you can often find what you need in related questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer. The hint about the Python Tooltips is super handy. I didn't knew about it.
It's also good to know that the documentation is offering more than I thought. I should just dig more deeper into it.